# How to change bgcolor of space below bottom navigation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation, flutter-theme

When using Gestures for Navigation, how can I change the background color of the area beneath bottom Navigation.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you specify the testing device name?

Comment: Testing device is Redmi Note 9 Pro

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, so after a lot of fiddling, I have arrived at this answer.

We need to wrap the material app/scaffold with `AnnotatedRegion`.

So I have changed my **main.dart** in the following way:

```
AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, //top status bar
        systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black, // navigation bar color, the one Im looking for
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, // status bar icons' color
        systemNavigationBarIconBrightness:
            Brightness.dark, //navigation bar icons' color
      ),
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
```

And this worked smoothly with a rebuild.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: thanks @Suman Baul u made my day https://stackoverflow.com/users/4084654/suman-baul

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your widgets with `Safe Area` widget. After you need to set `bottom` property false

Comment: Hi Yunus, thanks for your response. Even if I add the bottom property to false, I cannot change the color of the bottom navigation

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flutter_statusbarcolor_ns](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_statusbarcolor_ns) package to achieve your requirements.

The above package can help you to change your flutter app's statusbar's color or navigationbar's color programmatically.